# Is there a way to play Munchkin Quest with 5 people without the expansion?

Tags: munchkin-quest

Given that there are 2 extra colors on the color die, and you can [buy the pawns separately](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/pawns/), is there a way to play Munchkin Quest without the expansion?

I realize there are no stands for the monsters, but would any of the rules be affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rulesheet for expansion [here](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/munchkinquest/lookingfortrouble/lookingfortrouble_rules.pdf).
I took a glance on it, there are some special expansion-specific things, but I found nothing concerning gameplay changes, so I suppose you can buy (or make your own) munchkins and stands for the monsters of the appropriate colours and enjoy the game :-)
I can't recall any rule prohibiting it, and, as rules usually say, "Like we could stop you" ;-)